# group array with sub array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to find the easiest way to take an array that has like information and create an array with sub array. The newly created parent array should also sum the values that are found in the sub-array. This is the equivalent of an SQL statement that uses sum/group by.

This is the original array

```
[
    {
        'userId':1,
        'userName':'bob',
        'category':'shoes',
        'count':2
    },
    {
        'userId':1,
        'userName':'bob',
        'category':'rocks',
        'count':4
    },
    {
        'userId':1,
        'userName':'bob',
        'category':'bags',
        'count':3
    },
    {
        'userId':2,
        'userName':'sue',
        'category':'shoes',
        'count':1
    },
    {
        'userId':2,
        'userName':'sue',
        'category':'rocks',
        'count':7
    },
    {
        'userId':2,
        'userName':'sue',
        'category':'bags',
        'count':4
    },
]
```

This is what I want the newly created array to look like:

```
[
    {
        'userId':1,
        'userName':'bob',
        'purchases': [
            {'category':'shoes','count':'2'},
            {'category':'rocks','count':'4'},
            {'category':'bags','count':'3'}
        ],
        'totalCount' : 9
    },
    {
        'userId':2,
        'userName':'sue',
        'purchases': [
            {'category':'shoes','count':'1'},
            {'category':'rocks','count':'7'},
            {'category':'bags','count':'4'}
        ],
        'totalCount' : 12
    },  
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [**groupBy**](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) userId and then [**map**](http://underscorejs.org/#map) the groups to get the desired structure:

```
    var groups = _.groupBy(list, 'userId');

    var result = _.map(groups, function(user){
        return {
            userId: user[0].userId,
            userName: user[0].userName,
            purchases: _.map(user, function(purchase){
                return {
                    category: purchase.category,
                    count: purchase.count
                }
            }),
            totalCount: _.reduce(user, function(memo, purchase){
                return memo + purchase.count;
            }, 0)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) JavaScript SQL library:

This is an example:

```
var res = alasql('SELECT userId, FIRST(userName) as userName, \
                     ARRAY({category:category,[count]:[count]}) AS purchases,\
                     SUM([count]) AS totalCount FROM ? GROUP BY userId',[data]);
```

Try this example [at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/5rte00j6/7/). Compare speed with Lodash' solution [at jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/alasql-vs-lodash).

Comments:

1. I put [count] into square brackets, because COUNT is SQL reserved keyword
2. ARRAY() aggregator produce an array with values