# Group array items using object

Tags: javascript

My array is something like this:

```
myArray = [
  {group: "one", color: "red"},
  {group: "two", color: "blue"},
  {group: "one", color: "green"},
  {group: "one", color: "black"}
]
```

I want to convert this into:

```
myArray = [
  {group: "one", color: ["red", "green", "black"]}
  {group: "two", color: ["blue"]}
]
```

So, basically, group by `group`.

I'm trying:

```
for (i in myArray){
  var group = myArray[i].group;
  //myArray.push(group, {???})
}
```

I just don't know how to handle the grouping of similar group values.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? There are many closely related questions on SO already. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893667/group-by-json-array-using-jquery), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873228/javascript-group-by-array), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676026/group-array-with-sub-array).

Comment: Plenty of syntax errors there. Please test your code before posting.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First, in JavaScript it's generally not a good idea to iterate over arrays using `for ... in`. See [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) for details.

So you might try something like this:

```
var groups = {};
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  var groupName = myArray[i].group;
  if (!groups[groupName]) {
    groups[groupName] = [];
  }
  groups[groupName].push(myArray[i].color);
}
myArray = [];
for (var groupName in groups) {
  myArray.push({group: groupName, color: groups[groupName]});
}
```

Using the intermediary `groups` object here helps speed things up because it allows you to avoid nesting loops to search through the arrays. Also, because `groups` is an object (rather than an array) iterating over it using `for ... in` is appropriate.

**Addendum**

FWIW, if you want to avoid duplicate color entries in the resulting arrays you could add an `if` statement above the line `groups[groupName].push(myArray[i].color);` to guard against duplicates. Using jQuery it would look like this;

```
if (!$.inArray(myArray[i].color, groups[groupName])) {
  groups[groupName].push(myArray[i].color);
}
```

Without jQuery you may want to add a function that does the same thing as jQuery's `inArray`:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] === value)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
if (!groups[groupName].contains(myArray[i].color)) {
  groups[groupName].push(myArray[i].color);
}
```

Note that in either case you are going to slow things down a bit due to all the extra iteration, so if you don't need to avoid duplicate color entries in the result arrays I would recommend avoiding this extra code. There

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't work if you have two same objects in `_myArray_. 
With var myArray = [
  {group: "one", color: "red"},
  {group: "two", color: "blue"},
  {group: "one", color: "green"},
  {group: "one", color: "black"},
  {group: "one", color: "black"}
];`

You will get `myArray[0].color = ["red", "green",  "black", "black"]`

Comment: "Doesn't work" is subjective. OP never stated what to do in that case.

Comment: @Lends the OP never specified that as a requirement. In fact, given the comment from the OP I'd say this solution does indeed "work".

Comment: @neuronaut sorry, but maybe author just didn't check it and there is no any requirement except format of the objects in array. Never mind, your answer is confirmed one and I don't try to judge you. But it would be great if you would have time to correct this bug, so other people could use your code instead of dublicating this theme. Thanks!

Comment: The posted solution fills the requirement, the question says nothing about how to handle duplicates. A "fix" for an undefined problem is even likely to be more confusing to future readers who don't expect that functionality.

Comment: @Lends it's not a "bug" and as such needs no correcting. You seem to want me to solve a problem that may not even exist. In my experience solving problems that don't exist leads to poor performance and/or incorrect behavior in most software systems. That said, I suppose it wouldn't hurt to call it out separately for those who are curious - I'll add a bit to show how it would be done.

Comment: @neuronaut, as you wish

Answer (score 87):

Start by creating a mapping of group names to values.
Then transform into your desired format.

```js
var myArray = [
    {group: "one", color: "red"},
    {group: "two", color: "blue"},
    {group: "one", color: "green"},
    {group: "one", color: "black"}
];

var group_to_values = myArray.reduce(function (obj, item) {
    obj[item.group] = obj[item.group] || [];
    obj[item.group].push(item.color);
    return obj;
}, {});

var groups = Object.keys(group_to_values).map(function (key) {
    return {group: key, color: group_to_values[key]};
});

var pre = document.createElement("pre");
pre.innerHTML = "groups:\n\n" + JSON.stringify(groups, null, 4);
document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

Using Array instance methods such as [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) gives you powerful higher-level constructs that can save you a lot of the pain of looping manually.

Comment: Great answer. With Object.entries and ES6 we can also do `groups = Object.entries(group_to_values).map(([group, color]) => ({ group, color }));`

Comment: Awesome! my problem was pulling the keys to form an array of objects using `Object.keys`

Comment: how would I do to get another element in the final object if my original array looks like {group: "one", color: "red", size:"big"}?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using the new [`Map.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/groupBy) method. With it, you can create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) keyed by your `group` property and then use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a mapping function to convert the grouped Map into your desired array structure:

```js
const res = Array.from(Map.groupBy(arr, o => o.group), ([group, objs]) => ({group, color: objs.map(o => o.color)}));
```

```js
const arr = [ {group: "one", color: "red"}, {group: "two", color: "blue"}, {group: "one", color: "green"}, {group: "one", color: "black"} ];

const groupBy = "group", mergeOn = "color";
const res = Array.from(
  Map.groupBy(arr, obj => obj[groupBy]), 
  ([group, grouped]) => ({[groupBy]: group, [mergeOn]: grouped.map(o => o[mergeOn])})
);
console.log(res);
```

If you can't support the above approach, you can try using `.reduce()` with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as the accumulator, and then using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with its mapping function to map each grouped map-entry to an object:

```js
const arr = [{"group":"one","color":"red"},{"group":"two","color":"blue"},{"group":"one","color":"green"},{"group":"one","color":"black"}];

const res = Array.from(arr.reduce((m, {group, color}) => 
    m.set(group, [...(m.get(group) || []), color]), new Map
  ), ([group, color]) => ({group, color})
);

console.log(res);
```

The above as a reusable function:

```js
const arr = [{"group":"one","color":"red"},{"group":"two","color":"blue"},{"group":"one","color":"green"},{"group":"one","color":"black"}];

const groupAndMerge = (arr, groupBy, mergeInto) => {
  return Array.from(arr.reduce((m, obj) => 
      m.set(obj[groupBy], [...(m.get(obj[groupBy]) || []), obj[mergeInto]]), new Map
    ), ([grouped, merged]) => ({[groupBy]: grouped, [mergeInto]: merged})
  );
};

console.log(groupAndMerge(arr, "group", "color"));
```

If you have additional properties in your objects other than just `group` and `color`, you can take a more general approach by setting a grouped object as the map's values like so:

```js
const arr = [{"group":"one","color":"red"},{"group":"two","color":"blue"},{"group":"one","color":"green"},{"group":"one","color":"black"}];

const groupAndMerge = (arr, groupBy, mergeInto) => 
  Array.from(arr.reduce((m, o) => {
    const curr = m.get(o[groupBy]);
    return m.set(o[groupBy], {...o, [mergeInto]: [...(curr && curr[mergeInto] || []), o[mergeInto]]});
  }, new Map).values());

console.log(groupAndMerge(arr, 'group', 'color'));
```

If you can support [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and the [nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), you can simplify the above method to the following:

```js
const arr = [{"group":"one","color":"red"},{"group":"two","color":"blue"},{"group":"one","color":"green"},{"group":"one","color":"black"}];
const groupAndMerge = (arr, groupBy, mergeWith) =>
  Array.from(arr.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o[groupBy], {...o, [mergeWith]: [...(m.get(o[groupBy])?.[mergeWith] ?? []), o[mergeWith]]}), new Map).values());

console.log(groupAndMerge(arr, 'group', 'color'));
```

Answer (score 7):

Use lodash's `groupby` method

> Creates an object composed of keys generated from the results of running each element of collection thru iteratee. The order of grouped values is determined by the order they occur in collection. The corresponding value of each key is an array of elements responsible for generating the key. The iteratee is invoked with one argument: (value).

So with lodash you can get what you want in a single line. See below

```js
let myArray = [
  {group: "one", color: "red"},
  {group: "two", color: "blue"},
  {group: "one", color: "green"},
  {group: "one", color: "black"},
]
let grouppedArray=_.groupBy(myArray,'group')
console.log(grouppedArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the result is not the required data structure

Answer (score 6):

One option is:

```
var res = myArray.reduce(function(groups, currentValue) {
    if ( groups.indexOf(currentValue.group) === -1 ) {
      groups.push(currentValue.group);
    }
    return groups;
}, []).map(function(group) {
    return {
        group: group,
        color: myArray.filter(function(_el) {
          return _el.group === group;
        }).map(function(_el) { return _el.color; })
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dvgwodxq/

Comment: Very elegant and self contained, nice. My only gripe is it's not as instantly readable as a simpler `for` loop.

Comment: reduce, indexOf, map, filter, map seems overly complex to me.

Comment: @KingMob Define "complex". Those are regular array methods.

Comment: It works, but I need some time to go through the code and understand it. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @NunoNogueira You are very welcome. That's just one of the options.

Answer (score 5):

Beside the given approaches with a two pass approach, you could take a single loop approach by pushing the group if a new group is found.

```js
var array = [{ group: "one", color: "red" }, { group: "two", color: "blue" }, { group: "one", color: "green" }, { group: "one", color: "black" }],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    grouped = [];

array.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!groups[o.group]) {
        groups[o.group] = [];
        grouped.push({ group: o.group, color: groups[o.group] });
    }
    groups[o.group].push(o.color);
});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
myArray = [
  {group: "one", color: "red"},
  {group: "two", color: "blue"},
  {group: "one", color: "green"},
  {group: "one", color: "black"}
];


let group = myArray.map((item)=>  item.group ).filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i).sort((a, b)=> a - b).map(item=>{
    let new_list = myArray.filter(itm => itm.group == item).map(itm=>itm.color);
    return {group:item,color:new_list}
});
console.log(group);
```

Answer (score 2):

This version takes advantage that object keys are unique. We process the original array and collect the colors by group in a new object. Then create new objects from that group -> color array map.

```
var myArray = [{
      group: "one",
      color: "red"
    }, {
      group: "two",
      color: "blue"
    }, {
      group: "one",
      color: "green"
    }, {
      group: "one",
      color: "black"
    }];

    //new object with keys as group and
    //color array as value
    var newArray = {};

    //iterate through each element of array
    myArray.forEach(function(val) {
      var curr = newArray[val.group]

      //if array key doesnt exist, init with empty array
      if (!curr) {
        newArray[val.group] = [];
      }

      //append color to this key
      newArray[val.group].push(val.color);
    });

    //remove elements from previous array
    myArray.length = 0;

    //replace elements with new objects made of
    //key value pairs from our created object
    for (var key in newArray) {
      myArray.push({
        'group': key,
        'color': newArray[key]
      });
    }
```

Please note that this does not take into account duplicate colors of the same group, so it is possible to have multiple of the same color in the array for a single group.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using `reduce()` and `new Map()` to group the array. Use `Spread syntax` to convert set object into an array.

```js
var myArray = [{"group":"one","color":"red"},{"group":"two","color":"blue"},{"group":"one","color":"green"},{"group":"one","color":"black"}]

var result = [...myArray.reduce((c, {group,color}) => {
  if (!c.has(group)) c.set(group, {group,color: []});
  c.get(group).color.push(color);
  return c;
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the `Map` constructor callback for creating the groups (map keys). The second step is to populate the values of that map, and finally to extract the map's data in the desired output format:

```js
let myArray = [{group: "one", color: "red"},{group: "two", color: "blue"},
               {group: "one", color: "green"},{group: "one", color: "black"}];

let map = new Map(myArray.map(({group}) => [group, { group, color: [] }]));
for (let {group, color} of myArray) map.get(group).color.push(color);
let result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [{
      id: "123",
      name: "aaaaaaaa"
    }, {
      id: "123",
      name: "aaaaaaaa"
    }, {
      id: '456',
      name: 'bbbbbbbbbb'
    }, {
      id: '789',
      name: 'ccccccccc'
    }, {
      id: '789',
      name: 'ccccccccc'
    }, {
      id: '098',
      name: 'dddddddddddd'
    }];
//if you want to group this array
group(array, key) {
  console.log(array);
  let finalArray = [];
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    var newArray = [];
    array.forEach(function(element1) {
      if (element[key] == element1[key]) {
          newArray.push(element)
      }
    });
    if (!(finalArray.some(arrVal => newArray[0][key] == arrVal[0][key]))) {
        finalArray.push(newArray);
    }
  });
  return finalArray
}
//and call this function
groupArray(arr, key) {
  console.log(this.group(arr, key))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach with a reducer:

```js
myArray = [
  {group: "one", color: "red"},
  {group: "two", color: "blue"},
  {group: "one", color: "green"},
  {group: "one", color: "black"}
]

console.log(myArray.reduce( (acc, curr) => {
  const itemExists = acc.find(item => curr.group === item.group)
  if(itemExists){
    itemExists.color = [...itemExists.color, curr.color]
  }else{
    acc.push({group: curr.group, color: [curr.color]})
  }
  return acc;
}, []))
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives you unique colors, if you do not want duplicate values for color

```js
var arr = [
  {group: "one", color: "red"},
  {group: "two", color: "blue"},
  {group: "one", color: "red"},
  {group: "two", color: "blue"},
  {group: "one", color: "green"},
  {group: "one", color: "black"}
]

var arra = [...new Set(arr.map(x => x.group))]

let reformattedArray = arra.map(obj => {
   let rObj = {}
   rObj['color'] = [...new Set(arr.map(x => x.group == obj ? x.color:false ))]
       .filter(x => x != false)
   rObj['group'] = obj
   return rObj
})
console.log(reformattedArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

this repo offers solutions in lodash and alternatives in native Js, you can find how to implement groupby.
https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore#_groupby

Comment: This is helpful, but I think i'll just use the lodash approach since it's much easier to read!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function convert(items) {
    var result = [];

    items.forEach(function (element) {
        var existingElement = result.filter(function (item) {
            return item.group === element.group;
        })[0];

        if (existingElement) {
            existingElement.color.push(element.color);
        } else {
            element.color = [element.color];
            result.push(element);
        }

    });

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend array functionality with the next:

```
Array.prototype.groupBy = function(prop) {
  var result = this.reduce(function (groups, item) {
      const val = item[prop];
      groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
      groups[val].push(item);
      return groups;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(result).map(function(key) {
      return result[key];
  });
};
```

Usage example:

```js
/* re-usable function */
Array.prototype.groupBy = function(prop) {
  var result = this.reduce(function (groups, item) {
      const val = item[prop];
      groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
      groups[val].push(item);
      return groups;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(result).map(function(key) {
      return result[key];
  });
};

var myArray = [
  {group: "one", color: "red"},
  {group: "two", color: "blue"},
  {group: "one", color: "green"},
  {group: "one", color: "black"}
]

console.log(myArray.groupBy('group'));
```

Credits: [@Wahinya Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10642716/wahinya-brian)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `group` field is used to group in the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) step, it creates an object in the form of

```js
{
  one: {
    color: ["red", "green", "black"],
    group: "one"
  },
  two: {
    color: ["blue"],
    group: "two"
  }
}
```

So to get the values array in the desired format can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) on the `reduce` result

```js
let myArray = [
  {group: "one", color: "red"},
  {group: "two", color: "blue"},
  {group: "one", color: "green"},
  {group: "one", color: "black"}
]
let res = Object.values(myArray.reduce((acc,{group,color}) => {
  acc[group] = acc[group] || {group,color:[]}
  acc[group].color.push(color)
  return acc
},{}))

console.log(res)

/*
    //If need to overrite myArray
    myArray = Object.values(myArray.reduce((acc,{group,color}......
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Array Reducer method and Map method to group similar objects, In my case common properties are clientName, Id, groupId etc.

```js
const ClientDetails = [
{
    "checked": false,
    "data": {
        "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea53",
        "address": {
            "address1": "",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": ""
        },
        "Id": 110117,
        "clientName": "Apple",
        "groupId": "ff686b1c-0d83-4e9e-ac0e-edd4ed7a1579",
    },
    "isCollapsed": false,
    "validationErrors": [
        "Some data validations failed. Please correct and submit"
    ]
},
{
    "checked": false,
    "data": {
        "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea54",
        "address": {
            "address1": "",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": ""
        },
        "Id": 110117,
        "clientName": "Apple",
        "groupId": "ff686b1c-0d83-4e9e-ac0e-edd4ed7a1579",
    },
    "isCollapsed": false,
    "validationErrors": [
        "Some data validations failed. Please correct and submit"
    ]
},
{
    "checked": false,
    "data": {
        "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea55",
        "address": {
            "address1": "",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": ""
        },
        "Id": 110118,
        "clientName": "Mango",
        "groupId": "ff686b1c-0d83-4e9e-ac0e-edd4ed7a1589",
    },
    "isCollapsed": false,
    "validationErrors": [
        "Some data validations failed. Please correct and submit"
    ]
},
{
    "checked": false,
    "data": {
        "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea56",
        "address": {
            "address1": "",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": ""
        },
        "Id": 110118,
        "clientName": "Mango",
        "groupId": "ff686b1c-0d83-4e9e-ac0e-edd4ed7a1589",
    },
    "isCollapsed": false,
    "validationErrors": [
        "Some data validations failed. Please correct and submit"
    ]
},
{
    "checked": false,
    "data": {
        "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea57",
        "address": {
            "address1": "",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": ""
        },
        "Id": 110119,
        "clientName": "Orange",
        "groupId": "ff686b1c-0d83-4e9e-ac0e-edd4ed7a1599",
    },
    "isCollapsed": false,
    "validationErrors": [
        "Some data validations failed. Please correct and submit"
    ]
},
{
    "checked": false,
    "data": {
        "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea58",
        "address": {
            "address1": "",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": ""
        },
        "Id": 110119,
        "clientName": "Orange",
        "groupId": "ff686b1c-0d83-4e9e-ac0e-edd4ed7a1599",
    },
    "isCollapsed": false,
    "validationErrors": [
        "Some data validations failed. Please correct and submit"
    ]
},
{
    "checked": false,
    "data": {
        "accountId": "eb9e38a8-2e0e-46c2-b50a-fa5c7c18ea59",
        "address": {
            "address1": "",
            "city": "",
            "state": "",
            "zipcode": "",
            "country": ""
        },
        "Id": 110119,
        "clientName": "Orange",
        "groupId": "ff686b1c-0d83-4e9e-ac0e-edd4ed7a1599",
    },
    "isCollapsed": false,
    "validationErrors": [
        "Some data validations failed. Please correct and submit"
    ]
}
]

const deMergeMF = manageFunds => {
const result = [
    ...manageFunds
        .reduce((r, { Id, clientName, groupId, ...rest }) => {
            r.has(groupId) ||
                r.set(groupId, {
                    groupId,
                    clientName,
                    Id,
                    manageFunds: [],
                })

            r.get(groupId).manageFunds.push({ ...rest })

            return r
        }, new Map())
        .values(),
]

return result.map(alterResult => ({...alterResult, size: alterResult.manageFunds.length, bulkUploadErrorMessage: ''}))
}
console.log(deMergeMF(ClientDetails.map(item => item.data)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Array's `reduce` and `findIndex` methods, this can be achieved.

```js
var myArray = [{
  group: "one",
  color: "red"
}, {
  group: "two",
  color: "blue"
}, {
  group: "one",
  color: "green"
}, {
  group: "one",
  color: "black"
}];

var transformedArray = myArray.reduce((acc, arr) => {
  var index = acc.findIndex(function(element) {
    return element.group === arr.group;
  });
  if (index === -1) {
    return acc.push({
      group: arr.group,
      color: [arr.color]
    });
  }
  
  acc[index].color.push(arr.color);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(transformedArray);
```

By using `reduce` function, array is iterator and the new values are stored in `acc (accumulating)` parameter. To check if the object with given `group` already exists we can use `findIndex` function.

If `findIndex()` return -1, the value does not exist, so add the array in the `acc` parameter.

If `findIndex()` return index, then update the `index` with the `arr` values.

Answer (score -1):

Try (h={})

```
myArray.forEach(x=> h[x.group]= (h[x.group]||[]).concat(x.color) );
myArray = Object.keys(h).map(k=> ({group:k, color:h[k]}))
```

```js
let myArray = [
  {group: "one", color: "red"},
  {group: "two", color: "blue"},
  {group: "one", color: "green"},
  {group: "one", color: "black"},
];

let h={};

myArray.forEach(x=> h[x.group]= (h[x.group]||[]).concat(x.color) );
myArray = Object.keys(h).map(k=> ({group:k, color:h[k]}))

console.log(myArray);
```