# Group array of objects using a specific criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object/31688680?noredirect=1#comment51335513_31688680).

I'm sorry but I can't find the solution. I need to group an array of objects given by `dataObject` in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/kmu9zjcf/3/) by the property `objetivo` with the properties: `id`, `indicadores`, `objetivo` and `perspetiva`.

This is my code:

```
var res = dataObject.reduce(function(res, currentValue) {
    if ( res.indexOf(currentValue.objetivo) === -1 ) {
      res.push(currentValue.objetivo);
    }
    return res;
}, []).map(function(objetivo) {
    return {
        objetivo: objetivo,
        indicadores: dataObject.filter(function(_el) {
          return _el.objetivo === objetivo;
        }).map(function(_el) { return _el.indicador; }),
        perspetiva: dataObject.perspetiva, 
        id: dataObject.id
    }
});

console.log(res);
```

Which is grouping by `objetivo` correctly, but returning undefined for `perspetiva` and `id`.

Thanks for helping and sorry if this is duplicating other questions.

Comment: `dataObject` is an array and has neither a `perpetiva` property nor an `id` property. It would be easier if you included example input and output data in the question.

Comment: That's right, I need to filter the array and return the property 'perspetiva' and 'id' for those objects containg the 'objetivo' I'm looking for..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access `dataObject.id` and `.perspetiva`, but `dataObject` is your main array and doesn't have those fields.

After `reduce` has picked out the unique `objetiva`s, go back and find the items they came from:

```
.map(function(objetivo) {
    var items = dataObject.filter(function(_el) {
        return _el.objetivo === objetivo;
    });
```

Then you can find all the `indicador`s, and since it looks like `id` and `perspetiva` are consistent for items with the same `objetiva`, you can just pick from the first one.

```
    return {
        objetivo: objetivo,
        indicadores: items.map(function(_el) { return _el.indicador; }),
        perspetiva: items[0].perspetiva,
        id: items[0].id
    }
```

Here's [a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3aseh6fv/2/).

Comment: Exactly! I was trying to reach the object properties in the array which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I just noticed now that the proposed solution isn't grouping by the property 'objetivo'. See res[0] and res[3] and you'll see they're duplicated. The resulting array should have only 11 elements and it contains 19.