# How to merge objects with the same properties into a single Array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm reciving the next data

```
    [
      { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the1" },
      { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the2" },
      { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the3" },
      { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the1" },
      { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the2" },
      { id: "3", name: "test3", rName: "the1" }
    ]
```

I want to merge it by the id and push the rName's into an array to have this structure

```
    [
      { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: ["the1", "the2","the3"] },
      { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: ["the1", "the2"] },
      { id: "3", name: "test3", rName: ["the1"] }
    ]
```

I thought doing it with reduce but didn't succeed, if anyone can point me to the right direction it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like this:

In the reduce `accumulator`, check if there is already an item with same `id` as the current item being iterated. If yes, push the current item's `rName` to the `rName` array. Else, push a new item to the `accumulator`

```js
var data = [
      { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the1" },
      { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the2" },
      { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the3" },
      { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the1" },
      { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the2" },
      { id: "3", name: "test3", rName: "the1" }
      ];

const newArray = data.reduce((acc, {id,name,rName}) => {
    const existing = acc.find(a => a.id == id);
    if (existing)
        existing["rName"].push(rName);
    else
        acc.push({id,name,rName: [rName]})
    return acc
}, []);

console.log(newArray)
```

This is a one line, code-golf answer. (Got the idea from @Sébastien's answer):

```js
var data = [
  { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the1" },
  { id: "1", name: "test2", rName: "the2" },
  { id: "1", name: "test2", rName: "the3" },
  { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the1" },
  { id: "2", name: "test1", rName: "the2" },
  { id: "3", name: "test3", rName: "the1" }
]

const anotherArray = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, {id,name,rName}) =>
      ((acc[id] = acc[id] || {id,name,rName:[]})["rName"].push(rName), acc), {}));

console.log(anotherArray)
```

Comment: I like your answer, thank you for the explanation. Do you think there's a better way instead of reduce?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *better way*. If you don't want to use `reduce`, you could do the same thing with [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) by declaring an `acc` array outside and doing the same logic of whatever is being done in `reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty simple case of data reformatting. Code is below.

```js
var data = [
  { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the1" },
  { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the2" },
  { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the3" },
  { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the1" },
  { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the2" },
  { id: "3", name: "test3", rName: "the1" }
];
    
var reduced = Object.values(data.reduce(function(accumulator, element) {
  if (!accumulator[element.id]) {
    accumulator[element.id] = { id: element.id, name: element.name, rName: [] };
  }
  
  accumulator[element.id].rName.push(element.rName);
  return accumulator;
}, {}));
console.log(reduced);
```

The accumulator checks if the key by `element.id` exists in the accumulator. If it does not, it creates it. It then pushes the new `rName` on the existing stack. `Object.values()` is then used to make the conversion back to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Pure ES6

```
let result = obj.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let found = acc.find(i => i.id === item.id);
  found ? (found.rName = [...found.rName, item.rName]) : (acc = [...acc, { ...item, rName: [item.rName] }]);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

If each `id` can determine a unique`name`, this will work:

```
let data = [
  { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the1" },
  { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the2" },
  { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the3" },
  { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the1" },
  { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the2" },
  { id: "3", name: "test3", rName: "the1" }
];

let result = [];

for (let item of data) 
{
    const index = result.findIndex(i => i.id === item.id);
    if (index < 0) {
        result.push({ id: item.id, name: item.name, rName: [item.rName] });
    }
    else {
        result[index].rName.push(item.rName);
    }
}
```

Please note this will not work when following data should accept:

```
[
  { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the1" },
  { id: "1", name: "test2", rName: "the2" },
  { id: "1", name: "test2", rName: "the3" },
  { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the1" },
  { id: "2", name: "test1", rName: "the2" },
  { id: "3", name: "test3", rName: "the1" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you adhere to use method 'reduce', you can do like this:

```
var arr = [
        { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the1" },
        { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the2" },
        { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the3" },
        { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the1" },
        { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the2" },
        { id: "3", name: "test3", rName: "the1" }
    ]
    var arr1 = arr.reduce(function (a1, a2) {
        if (a1 instanceof Array) {
            let lastItem = a1[a1.length - 1]
            if (lastItem.id == a2.id) {
                lastItem.rName.push(a2.rName)
            } else {
                a1.push({ ...a2, rName: [a2.rName] })
            }
            return a1
        } else {
            let result = []
            if (a1.id == a2.id) {
                result.push({ ...a1, rName: [a1.rName, a2.rName] })
            } else {
                result.push({ ...a1, rName: [a1, rName] })
                result.push({ ...a2, rName: [a2, rName] })
            }
            return result

        }

    })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1))
```

But I think you should do like this, for the code is more clear:

```
var arr = [
    { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the1" },
    { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the2" },
    { id: "1", name: "test1", rName: "the3" },
    { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the1" },
    { id: "2", name: "test2", rName: "the2" },
    { id: "3", name: "test3", rName: "the1" }
]
var map = new Map()
arr.forEach(function(item){
    if(map.has(item.id)){
        map.get(item.id).rName.push(item.rName)
    }else{
        map.set(item.id, {...item, rName: [item.rName]})
    }
})
var arr1 = Array.from(map.values())
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1))
```