# How to concat/insert itens in my array after group my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I get my `response` array with duplicate values. `Id`, `Name` and `Cod`, but there are itens differents like `Indicator`. So I [grouped my array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object) using reduce. This is my array:

```js
let myArray = [  
  {  
    "id":1,
    "name":"NAME1",
    "cod":"00CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":2,      
      "name":"MY-SECOND-NAME",
    }
  },
  {  
    "id":1,
    "name":"NAME1",
    "cod":"00CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":3,
      "name":"MY-FIST-NAME",
    }
  },
  {  
    "id":5,
    "name":"DWWW",
    "cod":"200CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":2,
      "name":"MY-SECOND-NAME",
    }
  },
  {  
    "id":5,
    "name":"DWWW",
    "cod":"200CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":3,
      "name":"MY-FIST-NAME",
    }
  }
]

console.log("My Array with duplicate values:" )
console.log(myArray)

    var group_to_values = myArray.reduce(function (obj, item) {
      obj[item.cod] = obj[item.cod] || [];
      obj[item.cod].push(item.indicator);
      return obj;
    }, {});

    var groups = Object.keys(group_to_values).map(function (key) {
      return {
        cod: key,
        indicatorItem: group_to_values[key]
      };
    });

console.log("My Array grouped:" )
console.log(groups)
```

However, since `reduce` uses only 1 item (`key`) I lose the other values as: `Id`, `Name`

So, I tried to use a `.map()` and `.filter()` to find for items like `id` and`name` using `cod` as a reference, but I did not get much success. I'm going somewhere, but I do not know where :/

As I'm comparing item by item, the end of my return will always be the last item (`cod`) in my array. I understand that so the return is only the `cod 00CC`

This is my code:

```
let returnedItens = null

myArray.map(itemArray => {
  returnedItens = groups.filter(itemGroup => {
      if (itemArray.cod == itemGroup.cod) {
        return {
          id: itemArray.id,
          name: itemArray.name,
          cod: itemGroup.cod,
          indicator: itemGroup.indicator,
        }
      }
    })
  })
```

So, I would like to get this return with my code above:

```
[  
  {  
    "id":1,
    "name":"NAME1",
    "cod":"00CC",
    "indicator":[  
      {  
        "idIndicator":2,
        "name":"MY-SECOND-NAME",
      },
      {  
        "idIndicator":3,
        "name":"MY-FIST-NAME",
      }
    ]
  },
  {  
    "id":5,
    "name":"DWWW",
    "cod":"200CC",
    "indicator":[  
      {  
        "idIndicator":2,
        "name":"MY-SECOND-NAME",
      },
      {  
        "idIndicator":3,
        "name":"MY-FIST-NAME",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Please, someone can help me?
How I can do it?

Comment: If you would like to stick to using functional programming concept , see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to ggorlen for introducing `Object.values` method.
To achieve a more elegant and faster solution, you can stick to using reduce method with my following code :

```js
let myArray = [  
  {  
    "id":1,
    "name":"NAME1",
    "cod":"00CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":2,      
      "name":"MY-SECOND-NAME",
    }
  },
  {  
    "id":1,
    "name":"NAME1",
    "cod":"00CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":3,
      "name":"MY-FIST-NAME",
    }
  },
  {  
    "id":5,
    "name":"DWWW",
    "cod":"200CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":2,
      "name":"MY-SECOND-NAME",
    }
  },
  {  
    "id":5,
    "name":"DWWW",
    "cod":"200CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":3,
      "name":"MY-FIST-NAME",
    }
  }
]

let newArray = myArray.reduce(function(prev,next){

    let key = next.cod;
    if (!prev[key]){
       prev[key] = next;
       prev[key]["indicator"]=[prev[key]["indicator"]]
    } else {
       prev[key]["indicator"].push(next["indicator"])
    }
    return prev
},[])

console.log(Object.values(newArray))
```

Comment: Think of reduce like mapping, except reduce takes in two or more values and return a new state of values. By checking whether the new array has the duplicated keys or not, we can determine whether we need to create a new object or push to an existing key.

Comment: Thank you so much. This way is reaaly very simple to read and understand!

Comment: @Zkk, no problem. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an object with keys representing the data you'd like to reduce onto, namely, the `.cod` property. After grouping, use `Object.values()` to convert your objects back into an array. Time complexity is linear.

```js
let myArray = [ { "id":1, "name":"NAME1", "cod":"00CC", "indicator":{ "idIndicator":2, "name":"MY-SECOND-NAME", } }, { "id":1, "name":"NAME1", "cod":"00CC", "indicator":{ "idIndicator":3, "name":"MY-FIST-NAME", } }, { "id":5, "name":"DWWW", "cod":"200CC", "indicator":{ "idIndicator":2, "name":"MY-SECOND-NAME", } }, { "id":5, "name":"DWWW", "cod":"200CC", "indicator":{ "idIndicator":3, "name":"MY-FIST-NAME", } } ];
const result = {};

for (const o of myArray) {
  if (!(o.cod in result)) {
    result[o.cod] = o;
    result[o.cod].indicator = [o.indicator];
  }
  else {
    result[o.cod].indicator.push(o.indicator);
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is the correct way to do what you want.

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) both serve different purpose. Besides, you are using them incorrectly in your code snippet. (Please read the referenced docs)

[`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is to transform every array value.

[`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is to extract certain array value(s).

[`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is to return a single output by accessing every array value.

Below is a working code and explanation:

```js
let myArray = [  
  {  
    "id":1,
    "name":"NAME1",
    "cod":"00CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":2,      
      "name":"MY-SECOND-NAME",
    }
  },
  {  
    "id":1,
    "name":"NAME1",
    "cod":"00CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":3,
      "name":"MY-FIST-NAME",
    }
  },
  {  
    "id":5,
    "name":"DWWW",
    "cod":"200CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":2,
      "name":"MY-SECOND-NAME",
    }
  },
  {  
    "id":5,
    "name":"DWWW",
    "cod":"200CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":3,
      "name":"MY-FIST-NAME",
    }
  }
]

// If you don't understand what are `acc` and `curr`, read the doc I referenced above
const ret = myArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {

  // Get the index of the obj with same id, name and cod
  const indexOfSameObj = acc.findIndex(obj => {
    return obj.id === curr.id
        && obj.name === curr.name
        && obj.cod === curr.cod
  });
  
  if (indexOfSameObj >= 0){
    // If same obj exists, push next.indicator to the same obj
    acc[indexOfSameObj].indicator.push(curr.indicator);
  } else {
    // If same obj doesn't exist, push new obj with new structure to reduced array
    acc.push({
      id: curr.id,
      name: curr.name,
      cod: curr.cod,
      indicator: [curr.indicator]  // Make `.indicator` an array
    });
  }

  // Return the new reduced array
  return acc;

}, []  /* This empty array is the initial value of reduced array */);

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest code that I can come with. It simply loops an array and match items and if found delete from inner array as well as outer array to remove duplicates.

```js
let myArray = [  
  {  
    "id":1,
    "name":"NAME1",
    "cod":"00CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":2,      
      "name":"MY-SECOND-NAME",
    }
  },
  {  
    "id":1,
    "name":"NAME1",
    "cod":"00CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":3,
      "name":"MY-FIST-NAME",
    }
  },
  {  
    "id":5,
    "name":"DWWW",
    "cod":"200CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":2,
      "name":"MY-SECOND-NAME",
    }
  },
  {  
    "id":5,
    "name":"DWWW",
    "cod":"200CC",
    "indicator":{  
      "idIndicator":3,
      "name":"MY-FIST-NAME",
    }
  }
]
const copyMyArray = [...myArray];

myArray.forEach((arr, i) => {
  copyMyArray.forEach((ar, index) => {
    let same = arr.id === ar.id && arr.name === ar.name && arr.cod === ar.cod;
    if(same && index !== i) {
      arr.indicator = [ arr.indicator, ar.indicator];
      // do not loop next time
      copyMyArray.splice(index, 1);
      // remove from first array 
      myArray.splice(index, 1)
    }

  })
})
console.log(myArray)
```