# Combine two objects in an array into a single object if the object properties are the same and convert the unique properties into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures

Input -

```
[
  {color:'red', shape:'circle', size:'medium'},
  {color:'red', shape:'circle', size:'small'}
]
```

Output -

```
[
  {color:'red', shape:'circle', size:['medium','small']}
]
```

How can this be achieved in Javascript?

Comment: Would you want 
[
  {color:'red', shape:'square', size:'small'},
  {color:'red', shape:'circle', size:'small'}
]
to output 
[
  {color:'red', shape:['circle', 'square'], size:'small'}
]
and how would you handle the case where there are three objects, and all of them match two thing in common, but not the same two things? Will it only ever be two items?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for an ideal solution that can handle duplicate properties in the objects.

Comment: But, then, as @Cal Irvine says, what do you expect to get as output when input is something like this:  `[ {color:'red', shape:'circle', size:'medium'}, {color:'red', shape:'circle', size:'small'}, {color:'red', shape:'square', size:'small'}, {color:'blue', shape:'circle', size:'medium'}]`? How will you group the items?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object)

Comment: In that case I would expect an output of [ {color:'red', shape:'circle', size:['medium', 'small']}, {color:'red', shape:'square', size:'small'}, {color:'blue', shape:'circle', size:'medium'}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to group based on `color` and `shape`, you could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Create an accumulator object with each unique combination of those 2 properties separated by a `|` as key. And the object you want in the output as their value. Then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get those objects as an array.

```js
const input = [
  {color:'red', shape:'circle', size :'medium'},
  {color:'red', shape:'circle', size:'small'},
  {color:'blue', shape:'square', size:'small'}
];

const merged = input.reduce((acc, { color, shape, size }) => {
  const key = color + "|" + shape;
  acc[key] = acc[key] || { color, shape, size: [] };
  acc[key].size.push(size);
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

This is what the merged/accumulator looks like:

```
{
  "red|circle": {
    "color": "red",
    "shape": "circle",
    "size": [
      "medium",
      "small"
    ]
  },
  "blue|square": {
    "color": "blue",
    "shape": "square",
    "size": [
      "small"
    ]
  }
}
```

You can make it dynamic by creating an array of keys you'd want to group by:

```js
const input = [
      { color: 'red', shape: 'circle', size: 'medium' },
      { color: 'red', shape: 'circle', size: 'small' },
      { color: 'blue', shape: 'square', size: 'small' }
   ];
const groupKeys = ['color', 'shape'];

const merged = input.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const key = groupKeys.map(k => o[k]).join("|");
  
  if (!acc[key]) {
    acc[key] = groupKeys.reduce((r, k) => ({ ...r, [k]: o[k] }), {});
    acc[key].size = []
  }
  
  acc[key].size.push(o.size)
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a general function which takes an array of objects and array of keys to match as its parameters.

You can do that in following steps:

- First use `reduce()` on the array of objects and set accumulator to empty array `[]`
- Get the other props(unique props) by using `filter()` on `Object.keys()`
- Then in each iteration find the element of the accumulator array whose all the given props matches with the current object.
- If the element is found then use `forEach()` other keys and push the values to to corresponding array.
- If element is not found then set each key to an empty array.
- At last return the result of `reduce()`

```js
const arr = [
  {color:'red', shape:'circle', size:'medium'},
  {color:'red', shape:'circle', size:'small'}
]

function groupByProps(arr,props){
  const res = arr.reduce((ac,a) => {
    let ind = ac.findIndex(b => props.every(k => a[k] === b[k]));
    let others = Object.keys(a).filter(x => !props.includes(x));
    if(ind === -1){
      ac.push({...a});
      others.forEach(x => ac[ac.length - 1][x] = []);
      ind = ac.length - 1
    }
    others.forEach(x => ac[ind][x].push(a[x]));
    return ac;
  },[])
  return res;
}

const res = groupByProps(arr,['color','shape'])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple `groupBy` function which accepts an array of objects and array of `props` to group on:

```js
let data = [
  {color:'red', shape:'circle', size:'medium'},
  {color:'red', shape:'circle', size:'small'}
]

let groupBy = (arr, props) => Object.values(arr.reduce((r,c) => {
  let key = props.reduce((a,k) => `${a}${c[k]}`, '')
  let otherKeys = Object.keys(c).filter(k => !props.includes(k))
  r[key] = r[key] || {...c, ...otherKeys.reduce((a,k) => (a[k] = [], a),{})}
  otherKeys.forEach(k => r[key][k].push(c[k]))
  return r
}, {}))

console.log(groupBy(data, ['color','shape']))
```

The idea is to use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and basically create a string key of the passed in props. For the other fields create an array and keep pushing values there on each iteration.