# Group association in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having coming up with a logic to group similar items.

I have tried looping through the array and extracting the group value but problem I ran into was finding a way to associate it with the other key/value pair in the object.

```js
input = [{
  group: 1,
  name: 'bob'
}, {
  group: 1,
  name: 'bob'
}, {
  group: 0,
  name: 'mike'
}]

output = [{
  1: ['bob', 'bob']
}, {
  0: ['mike']
}]
```

Comment: you can use .map to solve this problem

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate but it's very similar. You just need modify the last step from the answers [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let array = [{
  group: 1,
  name: "bob"
}, {
  group: 1,
  name: "bob"
}, {
  group: 0,
  name: "mike"
}];

const groupedObj = array.reduce((result, item) => {
  if (!result[item.group]) {
    result[item.group] = []
  }
  result[item.group].push(item.name)
  return result
}, {})

let grouped = (Object.entries(groupedObj)).map((item) => ({
  [item[0]]: item[1]
}))

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: This is similar to what I was going to suggest. I would definitely use reduce over map for this.