# Javascript collect object values in an array grouped on a property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am receiving the following array from an API response:

```
[ 
  {group: '1', , value: 'a'}
  {group: '1', , value: 'b'}
  {group: '2', , value: 'c'}
  {group: '2', , value: 'd'}
]
```

I want to convert it to the following (want order of groups as received, values can be ordered in any way):

```
[
  {group: '1', values: ['b', 'a'] },
  {group: '2', values: ['c', 'd'] },
]
```

Which Javascript function will be the most efficient to convert it?

I am able to do this by:

```
let result = [];

data.reduce((groupNumber, input) => {
  if (!groupNumber[input.group]) {
     groupNumber[input.group] = {group: input.group, values: []};
     result.push(groupNumber[input.group]);
  }
  groupNumber[input.group].values.push(input);
  return groupNumber;
}, {});
```

Is `reduce` the correct function to be used here? Is there a more efficient approach?

Secondly, will `reduce` preserve the order in the result? If I am actually receiving the data with group 1 entries first, group 2 next, and so on, can I rely on `result` being ordered similarly?

Note that I only care about the order of the groups, not about the values inside the group.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The title may be a little confusing. The example correctly explains what I want to achieve (basically, convert an array to an array of array)

Comment: Oh wait, I see it now, sorry

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853037/3082296) from the duplicate if you want to preserve the order

Comment: @adiga His current code actually does preserve the order, because he's pushing to a *separate* array inside the `.reduce` callback.

Comment: @CertainPerformance you are right. They are using accumulator as a mapper. Sorry OP

Comment: Could we no use a Map or a Set here?

Comment: @CertainPerformance should I reopen the question? It is POB / not reproducible since OP's code is fine / the duplicate has plenty of alternatives

Comment: My bad, I should have explained this. I do not care about the order inside the group. I only care that the group numbers are in the same order as received.

Comment: @adiga Yeah, half is moderately POB, but the other half is objectively answerable but trivial ("Yes."). I wouldn't object to someone reopening but wouldn't do it myself

Answer (score 0):

I would save my reply because we have a great explanation why your approach is great, because you have `O(N)` computational complexity (Thanks for the great comments to @[CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance)) and you iterate your array just one time.

**Testing whether `reduce` method preserve order of object keys:**

It looks like `reduce` method is not preserving order of keys. Here we see that keys are sorted in order how then iterated through source array `myArray`, however in Chrome browser this behavior is not reproducible(keys are sorted):

```js
var myArray = [{letter: 'c'}, {letter:'e'}, {letter: 'e'}, {letter:'b'}, {letter: 'c'}, {letter:'a'}, {letter:'b'}, {letter:'a'}, {letter: 'd'}, {letter: 'd'}, {letter: 'd'}, {letter: 'd'}];
var myOrderedKeys = myArray.reduce((a, {letter}) => {
a[letter] = a[letter] || letter;
a[letter] = letter;

return a;
}, {})

console.log(myOrderedKeys);
```

Another example where we have more than one letter:

```js
let notSimpleLetters = [{letter: 'ce'}, {letter:'ec'}, {letter: 'ec'}, {letter:'bw'}, {letter: 'ce'}, {letter:'aw'}, {letter:'ba'}, {letter:'aa'},
                    {letter: 'df'}, {letter: 'cb'}, {letter: 'dc'}, {letter: 'da'}];
let notSimpleKeys = notSimpleLetters.reduce((a, {letter}) => {
a[letter] = a[letter] || letter;
a[letter] = letter;

return a;
}, {})

console.log(notSimpleKeys);
```

Comment: It doesn't answer either of the questions (of whether `.reduce` is appropriate, or whether it preserves the property order), *and* does not produce the right output for different orderings of `data`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you for clarification. I've updated my answer. I would be really happy to get any notes. Thanks!:)

Comment: OP's current code *does* actually preserve key order. Reducing into an object using numeric keys will not preserve the order *of the properties on the object*, but OP isn't iterating over the object later, so it's OK. (though, this is confusing, which is why I'd personally avoid `reduce` here)

Comment: Object property order *can* be relied on, if the properties are non-numeric. The specification does not say this *yet*, but it will soon, and all engines implement it anyway.

Comment: Well, in OP's code, at least the order of the `group` objects in the array is proper, but the `values` property does need to be fixed to be an array of strings rather than an array of objects

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am sorry, maybe it is a dumb question, however, in my view, `values: ['b', 'a']` is array of strings, not array of objects?

Comment: Yep. OP's code is preserving the desired *order*, even over numeric keys, but his `value` properties are malformed. Your code fixes the `value` properties but doesn't preserve the `group` order because each `group` is numeric.

Comment: @CertainPerformance please, see my updated answer. now it outputs the desired result which is shown in OP's question.

Comment: `.sort((a, b) => (a > b ? -1 : 1));` works if you know in advance whether the `group` in the data is in ascending or descending order, but that's probably not the case, and also won't work for, eg, an original order of `{ group: 3 }, { group: 1 }, { group: 2 }`. It also increases computational complexity to `O(n log n)` from `O(n)`. I'd prefer to stick to OP's current method (of pushing to a completely separate array, while also using an object for easy lookup)

Answer (score 0):

Actually either by using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or any other `Array` methods, the order will be always preserved as they will be executed from index 0 till the end of the `array`.

But [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is mainly used to accumulate the `array` elements into a single element, it's not the best method for doing such thing but it can be used as well.

Note that your actual code using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) isn't returning the right output.

In my opinion I think [**`Array.map()` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) is better in this case, but it should be used in combination with [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) to remove duplicate elements that will be kept with `map()`:

```
var result = data.map(v => {
  v.values = data.filter(e => e.group == v.group).map(x => x.value);
  delete v.value;
  return v;
}).filter(x => !x.values.some(e => !e));
```

**Demo:**

```js
let data = [{
  group: '1',
  value: 'a'
}, {
  group: '1',
  value: 'b'
}, {
  group: '2',
  value: 'c'
}, {
  group: '2',
  value: 'd'
}];


var result = data.map(v => {
  v.values = data.filter(e => e.group == v.group).map(x => x.value);
  delete v.value;
  return v;
}).filter(x => !x.values.some(e => !e));

console.log(result);
```