# Find duplicate value object JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a problem with javascript code
I have an array of the type

```js
var array = [{
    name: "Name 1",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Name 2",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Name 3",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Name 1",
    id: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Name 1",
    id: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Name 2",
    id: 6
  },
];
```

I'd like to get this:

```
var newArray = [{
    name: "Name 1",
    id: [1, 4, 5]
  },
  {
    name: "Name 2",
    id: [2, 6]
  },
  {
    name: "Name 3",
    id: 3
  },
];
```

But I can't
I tried with a `.find()` but it doesn't work
Can you give me some leads please

Comment: Basically create a lookup-structure by your key field (seems to be `name` here) and put all your items there. Then just filter all lookup-entries by the number of items included.

Comment: `find` seems pointless here--you need to iterate the original array, put each `name` into an object, adding the `id` to an initially-empty array, then take the new object and build an array out of its key-value pairs.

Comment: So basically what you want is if there are more than one of the "same" objects then create an array of ids. If there's only one, leave the single value as a number. Am I correct?

Comment: Also relevant: [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` with a `Map`, for O(n) performance, as there are no nested loops:

```js
const array = [
  { name: "Name 1", id: 1 },
  { name: "Name 2", id: 2 },
  { name: "Name 3", id: 3 },
  { name: "Name 1", id: 4 },
  { name: "Name 1", id: 5 },
  { name: "Name 2", id: 6 }
]

const out = [...array.reduce((a, o) => {
  const e = a.get(o.name)
  return (a.set(o.name, e ? Array.isArray(e) ? e.concat(o.id): [e, o.id] : o.id), a)
}, new Map())].map(([k, v]) => ({ name: k, id: v }))

console.log(out)
```

Comment: OP doesn't want an an array if only item is present.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` to create an object and then use `Object.values` to get an array. You can use `map()` after this to remove  the array for those elements which have only a single `id`.

```js
var array = [{
    name: "Name 1",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Name 2",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Name 3",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Name 1",
    id: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Name 1",
    id: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Name 2",
    id: 6
  },
];

const res = Object.values(array.reduce((ac, a) => {
  if(!ac[a.name]){
    ac[a.name] = {...a, id: []}
  }
  ac[a.name].id.push(a.id);
  return ac;
},{})).map(x => ({...x, id: x.id.length === 1 ? x.id[0] : x.id}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: OP doesn't want an array for `id:3`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Array.reduce()` like this :

```js
var array = [{
        name: "Name 1",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        name: "Name 2",
        id: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Name 3",
        id: 3
    },
    {
        name: "Name 1",
        id: 4
    },
    {
        name: "Name 1",
        id: 5
    },
    {
        name: "Name 2",
        id: 6
    },
];

var output = array.reduce((acc, current) => {
    if (exist = acc.find(p => p.name == current.name)) {
        if(!Array.isArray(exist.id)){
          exist.id = [exist.id];
        }
        exist.id.push(current.id);
    } else {

        acc.push(current)
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: This creates an nested array

Comment: The `id` array in the first element is not correct. Its a nested array.

Comment: @MaheerAli You are right. It's updated now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce()` for that. This example produces **exactly** the same output you expect:

```js
var array = [
  {
    name: "Name 1",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Name 2",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Name 3",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Name 1",
    id: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Name 1",
    id: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Name 2",
    id: 6
  }
];

var output = array.reduce(function(res, curr) {

  var existing = res.find(function(el) { return el.name === curr.name; });
  if (existing) {
    if (Array.isArray(existing.id))
      existing.id.push(curr.id);
    else
      existing.id = [existing.id, curr.id]
  } else {
    res.push(curr);
  }
  
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```