# How to group an array object based on three keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

based on this question [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object)

I quoted from this answer, answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094311/1983

so I get data from this jquery then I parsed it, after that I push it to variable

the data that I get from myurl is like this

```
{"pname":"some1","datax":2.0643278,"prov":"11","datay":1},{"pname":"some1","datax":3.2142857142857144,"prov":"11","datay":1},{"pname":"some2","datax":1.125,"prov":"12","datay":1},{"pname":"some2","datax":1.6666666666666667,"prov":"12","datay":2}
```

this is how my array begin

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
                        url: "myurl",
                        method: "GET",
                        success: function(data) {

var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(data);

var result1 = [
  (function(data) {
    let tmp = [];

    data.forEach(e => {
      tmp.push({
        type: "firstid",
        prov: e.prov,
        name: e.pname,
        showInLegend:false,
        dataPoints:[{x:e.datax, y:e.datay}],
      })
    });

    return tmp;
  })(parsedJSON)
];
```

from there I got result1[0] and if I console log it, it will be like this

```
[        { type: "firstid",
           prov: 11,
           name: some1,
           showInLegend:false,
           dataPoints:[{x:2.0643278, y:1}] 
         },
         { type: "firstid",
           prov: 11,
           name: some1,
           showInLegend:false,
           dataPoints:[{x:3.2142857142857144, y:1}] 
         },
         { type: "firstid",
           prov: 12,
           name: some2,
           showInLegend:false,
           dataPoints:[{x:1.125, y:1}] 
         },
         { type: "firstid",
           prov: 12,
           name: some2,
           showInLegend:false,
           dataPoints:[{x:1.6666666666666667, y:1}] 
         }]
```

I want to get some array to be like this when I console log it :

```
[        { type: "firstid",
           prov: 11,
           name: some1,
           showInLegend:false,
           dataPoints:[ {x:2.0643278, y:1}, 
                        {x:3.2142857142857144, y:1}] 
         },
         { type: "firstid",
           prov: 12,
           name: some2,
           showInLegend:false,
           dataPoints:[ {x:1.125, y:1}, 
                        {x:1.6666666666666667, y:1}] 
         }]
```

I spent my time trying to figure it out with array merge but it seems I can't figure it out, any help would be nice

Comment: Show us your attempt so we can help you from there. And could you give us the context on what you want to do with your code?

Comment: ok, I will edit my question

Comment: This is an array of objects `[{...}, {...},...]` not a multidimensional array `[[...], [...],...]`

Comment: alright Im sorry, I already edited the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype.find` should do the trick.

`reduce` loops over every element in the array. It starts with an empty array: `[]`. The code then checks with `find` if the elements is already in the new array. If so add the `dataPoints` to the existing array. If it doesn't exist, push the object to the new array.

```js
const obj = [{"pname":"some1","datax":2.0643278,"prov":"11","datay":1},{"pname":"some1","datax":3.2142857142857144,"prov":"11","datay":1},{"pname":"some2","datax":1.125,"prov":"12","datay":1},{"pname":"some2","datax":1.6666666666666667,"prov":"12","datay":2}];

objReduced = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const dbItem = acc.find( element => element.prov === cur.prov);
  if (dbItem)
  {
    dbItem.dataPoints.push({x: cur.datax, y: cur.datay});
  }
  else
  {
    acc.push({  type: "firstid",
                prov: cur.prov,
                name: cur.pname,
                showInLegend: false,
                dataPoints: [{x: cur.datax, y: cur.datay}]
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(objReduced);
```

```css
obj = [{
    type: "firstid",
    prov: 11,
    name: "some1",
    showInLegend: false,
    dataPoints: [{
      x: 2.0643278,
      y: 1
    }]
```

Comment: thanks this one work well in my code, god bless you

Answer (score 1):

Based on your approach I will try to just push if the element is not present, if it is present, then push to the dataPoints array on the existing element. I haven't tried this, but it could work.

```
data.forEach(e => {
    const tempIndex = tmp.findIndex(el => el.prov === e.prov);
    if (tempIndex) {
        tmp[tempIndex].dataPoints.push({ x: e.datax, y: e.datay });
    } else {
        tmp.push({
            type: "firstid",
            prov: e.prov,
            name: e.pname,
            showInLegend: false,
            dataPoints: [{ x: e.datax, y: e.datay }],
        })
    }
});
```

Please let me know if this edited approach is better

Comment: I tried this one but the dataPoints is not grouped by the id, it is still separated tho'

Comment: @attaroqqi I edited the approach for something that might just work, let me know if that solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

This one will also check for duplicate items in dataPoints array before merging them:

```js
const data = [{
    type: "firstid",
    prov: 11,
    name: "some1",
    showInLegend: false,
    dataPoints: [{
      x: 2.0643278,
      y: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    type: "firstid",
    prov: 11,
    name: "some1",
    showInLegend: false,
    dataPoints: [{
      x: 3.2142857142857144,
      y: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    type: "firstid",
    prov: 12,
    name: "some2",
    showInLegend: false,
    dataPoints: [{
      x: 1.125,
      y: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    type: "firstid",
    prov: 12,
    name: "some2",
    showInLegend: false,
    dataPoints: [{
      x: 1.6666666666666667,
      y: 1
    }]
  }
];

const res = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const groupKey = ['type', 'prov', 'name', 'showInLegend'].map(x => curr[x]).join('-');

  if (!acc[groupKey]) {
    acc[groupKey] = curr;
  } else {
    for (const { x: currX, y: currY } of curr.dataPoints) {
      for (const {  x: accX, y: accY } of acc[groupKey].dataPoints) {
        if ((currX + '-' + currY) !== (accX + '-' + accY)) {
          acc[groupKey].dataPoints.push({ x: currX, y: currY });
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```