# duplicates for array of objects into organized data structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have a array like this:

```
let obj = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'bob'
    },
        {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bob'
    },
        {
        id: 3,
        name: 'karl'
    },
        {
        id: 4,
        name: 'joe'
    },
        {
        id: 5,
        name: 'joe'
    },    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'rick'
    },
    
];
```

I need to write some javascript code to parse through the array and handle the duplicate names.

My desired outcome is:

```
let obj = [
    {
        id: [1,2],
        name: 'bob'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'karl'
    },
        {
        id: [4,5],
        name: 'joe'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'rick'
    },
];
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do the non grouped ids need to appear standalone (ie. not in an array)? If they can also be in an array, then this question will answer your question: [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31688459)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). If the existing element is an `array` then you need to push it into array else create an array and push the existing element in the array along with new `id`

```js
let obj = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "bob",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "bob",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "karl",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "joe",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "joe",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "rick",
  },
];

const result = obj.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { id, name } = curr;
  const findEl = acc.find((o) => o.name === name);
  if (findEl) {
    if (Array.isArray(findEl.id)) {
      findEl.id.push(id);
    } else {
      findEl.id = [findEl.id, id];
    }
  } else {
    acc.push({ id, name });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

You can improve its time complexity by introducing a dictionary and no need to find elements every time in `reduce`. But here order can change of the object inside `result`

```js
let obj = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "bob",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "bob",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "karl",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "joe",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "joe",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "rick",
  },
];

const dict = {};
obj.forEach((obj) => {
  const { id, name } = obj;
  if (dict[name]) {
    if (Array.isArray(dict[name])) {
      dict[name].push(id);
    } else {
      dict[name] = [dict[name], id];
    }
  } else {
    dict[name] = id;
  }
});

const result = Object.entries(dict).map(([name, id]) => ({ name, id }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.reduce() is useful in this case.

```js
let obj = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'bob'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bob'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'karl'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'joe'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'joe'
  }, {
    id: 6,
    name: 'rick'
  },
];
const mergeObjectByValue = (objArray) => {
  const newObjs = objArray.reduce((prev, {
    name,
    id
  }) => {
    (name in prev) ? prev[name].push(id): prev[name] = [id]
    return prev;
  }, {})
  return Object.entries(newObjs).map(([name, ids]) => ({
    name,
    id: ids.length > 1 ? ids : ids[0],
  }))
}
console.log(mergeObjectByValue(obj))
```