# How to group array of objects by key when object can have differnt types

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const input = [
    {
        "name" : "car",
        "sign" : "+",
        "options" : "benz"
    },
    {
        "name" : "bike",
        "sign" : "+",
        "options" : "pulsar"
    },
    {
        "name" : "bike",
        "sign" : "+",
        "options" : "enfield"
    },
    {
        "name" : "car",
        "sign" : "+",
        "options" : ["toyota","hyundai","benz"]
    },
    {
        "name" : "",
        "sign" : "",
        "options" : "" 
    },
    {
        "name" : "car",
        "sign" : "+",
        "options" : ["audi", "ford"]
    }
]
```

The input structure is like this: every object has 3 key-value pairs.

1. All of them can be empty
2. It can have valid values:

   a. The options can either be a string

   b. Or it can be an array

I dont want the objects with values of "" (empty string) to be added in  the output, The output should be like this:

```
[
    {"car" : [ "benz", "toyota","hyundai", "audi", "ford"]},
    {"bike" : ["pulsar","enfield" ]}
]
```

The various other answers do not show how to handle when the object value can be either an array or a string, So I'm writing a new question.

I am not sure if I have to use reduce or map.
Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object) most of these use `push()` to add to the accumulator, but look at [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to fit your case. (it accepts both strings or arrays as parameters)

Comment: No, in that answer, they only have a string in color. But in my case, the "options" key can either have a string or array of strings as value, as I have mentioned.

Comment: Did you read my comment? `concat()` accepts either a string or an array.

Comment: I tried that. When it encounters an object with "" as a value for any key, it is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a reduce function adding the conditions tha you want.

```js
const input = [
    {
        "name": "car",
        "sign": "+",
        "options": "benz"
    },
    {
        "name": "bike",
        "sign": "+",
        "options": "pulsar"
    },
    {
        "name": "bike",
        "sign": "+",
        "options": "enfield"
    },
    {
        "name": "bike",
        "sign": "+",
        "options": "enfield"
    },
    {
        "name": "car",
        "sign": "+",
        "options": ["toyota", "hyundai"]
    },
    {
        "name": "",
        "sign": "",
        "options": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "car",
        "sign": "+",
        "options": ["audi", "ford"]
    }
]

let grouped = input.reduce(function (r, a) {
    if (a.name !== "") {
        r[a.name] = r[a.name] || [];
        if (Array.isArray(a.options)) {
            r[a.name] = Array.from( new Set (r[a.name].concat(a.options)))
        } else {
            r[a.name].push(a.options)
            r[a.name] = Array.from( new Set (r[a.name]));
        }

    }
    return r;
}, {});
let mapped = Object.entries(grouped).map(([key, value])=>{return{[key]:value}})

console.log(mapped)
```

Comment: Close, OP is looking for an array of objects.

Comment: But the array values will have dulpicate values. For ex, if there is "benz" in 2 objects, then the result will have "benz" twice {"car": ["benz","benz"]. How to get rid of these duplicated items

Comment: @ChaitraD edited with Set() to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @pilchard you totally right. How can I made an array of object rewritting the reduce function without using another map?

Comment: @ChaitraD I edited the answer again to add the map function, so theoutput is the same that you posted.

Comment: what is r and a in reduce? @RubénVega

Comment: I use r and a as "reducer" and "actual". The reduce funtion iterates, and for each iteration the current value will be the "actual", and the "reducer" is the acumulator. You could name those values as you want. More info about reduce [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly standard 'group by' operation, grouping by one property and accumulating another into an array.

In order to accommodate both strings and arrays you use [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to add the `options` value into the accumulator. Concat accepts either individual values or arrays of values and flattens the latter out into the target array. To avoid duplicates you can use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).The snippet below only adds elements to the accumulator if both `name` and `options` are truthy.

```js
const input = [
  { "name": "", "sign": "+", "options": "benz" }, // blank 'name' property
  { "name": "bike", "sign": "+", "options": "" }, // blank 'options' property
  { "name": "bike", "sign": "+", "options": "enfield" },
  { "name": "car", "sign": "+", "options": ["toyota", "hyundai"] },
  { "name": "car", "sign": "", "options": "ford" },
  { "name": "car", "sign": "+", "options": ["audi", "ford"] }]

const result = Object.values(
  input.reduce((acc, { name, options }) => {
    if (name && options) {
      const category = (acc[name] || (acc[name] = { [name]: [] }));
      category[name] = [...new Set(category[name].concat(options))];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {}));

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Alternatively, to avoid creating a new Set on each iteration, you can accumulate into a Set and then map the result of the `reduce()` call and convert each set to an array.

```js
const input = [
  { "name": "", "sign": "+", "options": "benz" }, // blank 'name' property
  { "name": "bike", "sign": "+", "options": "" }, // blank 'options' property
  { "name": "bike", "sign": "+", "options": "enfield" },
  { "name": "car", "sign": "+", "options": ["toyota", "hyundai"] },
  { "name": "car", "sign": "", "options": "ford" },
  { "name": "car", "sign": "+", "options": ["audi", "ford"] }]

const result = Object.entries(
  input.reduce((acc, { name, options }) => {
    if (name && options) {
      acc[name] || (acc[name] = new Set);
      [].concat(options).forEach(option => acc[name].add(option));
    }
    return acc;
  }, {}))
  .map(([name, options]) => ({ [name]: [...options] }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Since it seems you can't use ES6 iterators here is an option using just an `Array#includes()` check to avoid duplicates.

```js
const input = [
  { "name": "", "sign": "+", "options": "benz" }, // blank 'name' property
  { "name": "bike", "sign": "+", "options": "" }, // blank 'options' property
  { "name": "bike", "sign": "+", "options": "enfield" },
  { "name": "car", "sign": "+", "options": ["toyota", "hyundai"] },
  { "name": "car", "sign": "", "options": "ford" },
  { "name": "car", "sign": "+", "options": ["audi", "ford"] }]

const result = Object.values(
  input.reduce((acc, { name, options }) => {
    if (name && options) {
      const category = (acc[name] || (acc[name] = { [name]: [] }));
      [].concat(options).forEach(option => {
        if (!category[name].includes(option)) category[name].push(option)
      });
    }
    return acc;
  }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES3

```js
var input = [
  { "name": "", "sign": "+", "options": "benz" },
  { "name": "bike", "sign": "+", "options": "" },
  { "name": "bike", "sign": "+", "options": "enfield" },
  { "name": "car", "sign": "+", "options": ["toyota", "hyundai"] },
  { "name": "car", "sign": "", "options": "ford" },
  { "name": "car", "sign": "+", "options": ["audi", "ford"] }
];

var temp = {};

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  var name_ = input[i].name;
  var options_ = input[i].options;

  if (name_ !== undefined && name_ !== "" && options_ !== undefined && options_ !== "") {

    if (!temp.hasOwnProperty(name_)) {
      temp[name_] = {};
      temp[name_][name_] = [];
    }

    var options_ = [].concat(options_);

    for (var j = 0; j < options_.length; j++) {
      if (!temp[name_][name_].includes(options_[j])) {
        temp[name_][name_].push(options_[j]);
      }
    }

  }
}

var result = [];

for (var key_ in temp) {
  if (temp.hasOwnProperty(key_)) {
    result.push(temp[key_]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I am getting this error at ??
Module parse failed: Unexpected token 
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js  
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   }) => {
|     if (name) {
>       (acc[name] ??= {
|         [name]: []
|       })[name].push(...[].concat(options));

Comment: Edited to provide `||` short circuit instead of logical nullish assignment.

Comment: But the array values will have dulpicate values. For ex, if there is "benz" in 2 objects, then the result will have "benz" twice {"car": ["benz","benz"]. How to get rid of these duplicated itensm

Comment: Edited to avoid duplicates using Set

Comment: Type 'Set<unknown>' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.  TS2569       

    56 |           if (name && options) {
    57 |             const category = (acc[name] || (acc[name] = { [name]: [] }));
         category[name] = [...new Set(category[name].concat(options))];
       |                                  ^

Comment: As it notes in the error, use `--downlevelIteration` to allow ES6 iterators in compilation

Answer (score 1):

First convert the input to a map so that you can have everything in some key-value pair:

```
input.forEach((e)=>{
if(!(e["name"] in tempMap)){
    tempMap[e["name"]] = []
}
if(typeof e["options"] == typeof 'test'){
        tempMap[e["name"]].push(e["options"])
}else
    tempMap[e["name"]].push(...e["options"])
})
```

then convert it to whatever form you like

```
output = []
Object.keys(tempMap).forEach((e)=>{
    obj = {}
    obj[e] = tempMap[e]
    if(e != '')
        output.push(obj)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to achieve your requirements. Check this out-

```js
const input=[{name:"car",sign:"+",options:"benz"},{name:"bike",sign:"+",options:"pulsar"},{name:"bike",sign:"+",options:"enfield"},{name:"car",sign:"+",options:["toyota","hyundai"]},{name:"",sign:"",options:""},{name:"car",sign:"+",options:["audi","ford","benz"]}];

const result = input.reduce((acc, {name, options}) => {
    // Check if the name is not empty
    if (name) {
    
      // Initialize the object key with empty array if not already initialized
      acc[name] ||= [];
      
      // Check if the options is an array then push the array using spread operation
      // Otherwise directly push the string.
      if (Array.isArray(options)) {
        acc[name].push(...options);
      } else {
        acc[name].push(options);
      }
    }
  return acc;
}, {});

// Convert the object into array of objects.
// This is redundant I believe. If you use the `result` object
// that would be more accessible for you.
const output = Object.entries(result).map(([key, value]) => {
  // Use Set to remove duplicate entries from the value array.
  return Object.fromEntries([[key, [...new Set(value)]]]);
});

console.log(output);

// If you don't need the array of object as output then the result object is enough for you.
// You can access the car and bike object easily in this case.
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: How to handle duplicate values in output ? For ex, if there is "benz" in 2 objects, then the result will have "benz" twice {"car": ["benz","benz"]. How to get rid of these duplicated items

Comment: Good point, the OP had changed his question and didn't mention the duplicate entries. BTW, I've updated my answer. It's `Set` for our rescue.

Answer (score 0):

I've done that...

```js
const input = 
  [ { name: 'car',  sign: '+', options: 'benz'                 } 
  , { name: 'bike', sign: '+', options: 'pulsar'               } 
  , { name: 'bike', sign: '+', options: 'enfield'              } 
  , { name: 'bike', sign: '+', options: 'enfield'              } 
  , { name: 'car',  sign: '+', options: [ 'toyota', 'hyundai'] } 
  , { name: '',     sign: '',  options: ''                     } 
  , { name: 'car',  sign: '+', options: [ 'audi', 'ford']      } 
  ] 

const result = Object.entries( input.reduce((a,{name,options})=>
  {
  if (name)
    (a[name] = a[name] ?? []).push(...[options].flat() )
  return a
  }, {})
  ).map(([k,v])=>({[k]:[...new Set(v)]})) // remove duplicates

console.log( result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
.as-console-row::after { display: none !important; }
```