# merge an array of objects where one property is the same, while transferring the unique values of another property into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, set

I have an array of objects in which most of the properties may be duplicates of each other, but one value may differ:

```
const originalArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'x', 'description': 'x', url: 'y' },
  { id: 2, name: 'x', 'description': 'x', url: 'z' }
]
```

I want to dedupe this array based on a difference of name, but retain the URL differences as an array in the deduped array:

```
const dedupedArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'x', 'description': 'x', url: ['y','z'] },
]
```

```
function removeDuplicatesByProperty(keyFn, array) {
  const mySet = new Set();
  return array.filter(function (x) {
    const key = keyFn(x),
      isNew = !mySet.has(key);
    if (isNew) mySet.add(key);
    return isNew;
  });
}

const dedupedArray = removeDuplicatesByProperty((x) => x.name, originalArray);
```

Comment: So the `id`s can be different, and you don't care about which you keep?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const originalArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'x', 'description': 'x', url: 'y' },
  { id: 2, name: 'x', 'description': 'x', url: 'z' }
]

const res = originalArray.reduce((a,b) => {
  const found = a.find(e => e.name == b.name);
  return found ? found.url.push(b.url) : a.push({...b, url:[b.url]}), a;
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the array to a Map, and merge duplicates using a `mergeFn`. Convert the `Map.values()` iterator back to an array using `Array.from()` or array spread:

```js
const originalArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'x', 'description': 'x', url: 'y' },
  { id: 2, name: 'x', 'description': 'x', url: 'z' }
]

const dedupeMerge = (keyFn, mergeFn, array) => Array.from(
  array.reduce((acc, o) => {
    const key = keyFn(o);
    
    if(!acc.has(key)) return acc.set(key, o);
    
    return acc.set(key, mergeFn(acc.get(key), o));
  }, new Map()).values()
);

const dedupedArray = dedupeMerge(
  x => x.name, 
  (o1, o2) => ({ ...o1, url: [o1.url, o2.url].flat() }),
  originalArray
);

console.log(dedupedArray);
```