# How to combine array of objects with common id in each object with ES6 functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Attaching the input and output formats.
`

```
//Input
[{"id":"146","catId":"25"},
{"id":"200","catId":"25"},
{"id":"250","catId":"55"}];
```

```
//Output expected
[{"catId":"25","topicIds":["146","200"]},
{"catId":"55","topicIds":["250"]}];
```

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merge an array of objects where one property is the same, while transferring the unique values of another property into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591078/merge-an-array-of-objects-where-one-property-is-the-same-while-transferring-the)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reduce` can be used for grouping problems. Here I'm grouping by `catId` and it will return a grouped object

```js
{
  25: {
    catId: "25",
    topicIds: ["146", "200"]
  },
  55: {
    catId: "55",
    topicIds: ["250"]
  }
}
```

Then to get the values array use `Object.values`

```js
let a = [{"id":"146","catId":"25"},
{"id":"200","catId":"25"},
{"id":"250","catId":"55"}];

let res = Object.values(a.reduce((acc,{id,catId}) => {
    acc[catId] = acc[catId] || {catId,topicIds:[]}
  acc[catId].topicIds.push(id)
  return acc
},{}))

console.log(res)
```