# Mapping through array of objects after filtering and displaying dynamic common property as a header

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array of objects:

```
  const students = [
    { name: 'Tom', class: "Blue" },
    { name: 'Pom', class: "Blue" },
    { name: 'Max', class: "Red" },
    { name: 'Alex', class: "Red" },
    { name: 'John', class: "Yellow" }
  ];
```

And I would like to group the return values by the class property, so I can achieve something similar to this in HTML:

```
Class Blue: Tom, Pom
Class Red: Max, Alex
Class Yellow: John
```

*note: the class property should be displayed once as HTML mark-up which is the reason I don't think [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects) at all..*

**How should I go about it?** I can user `filter()` (like below) but this is rather silly. I would ideally like to avoid doing this several times especially given the `class` property is dynamic (not known before hand).

```
const classRed = students.filter(student => student.class === "Red);
const classBlue = students.filter(student => student.class === "Blue);
...
```

I [started this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcw2emy6/37/), but not sure how to deal with this object to display how I want it.

I guess this question is about getting the right data structure so I can then map through it to display what I need, rather than simply sorting the array.

Comment: What is the structure you'd like your result object to have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object)

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` method to do the group by operation and use `Object.entries` to get the list of items to iterate.

Try like this

```
{
    Object.entries(
        students.reduce((prevValue, currValue) => {
            prevValue[currValue.class]
                ? prevValue[currValue.class].push(currValue.name)
                : (prevValue[currValue.class] = [currValue.name]);
            return prevValue;
        }, {})
    ).map(([classs, names]) => `Class ${classs}: ${names.join(", ")}`);
}
```

```js
function App({}) {
    const students = [
        { name: "Tom", class: "Blue" },
        { name: "Pom", class: "Blue" },
        { name: "Max", class: "Red" },
        { name: "Alex", class: "Red" },
        { name: "John", class: "Yellow" }
    ];

    return (
        <div>
            {Object.entries(
                students.reduce((prevValue, currValue) => {
                    prevValue[currValue.class]
                        ? prevValue[currValue.class].push(currValue.name)
                        : (prevValue[currValue.class] = [currValue.name]);
                    return prevValue;
                }, {})
            ).map(([classs, names]) => (
                <div>{`Class ${classs}: ${names.join(", ")}`}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

JS Fiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/9ahtz2jd/11/

NOTE: Always try to use `filter`, `map`, `reduce` functions.

[image]

Comment: @Chris, check this out !!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new object with the name of the classes as keys and an array with the names of the students as values.

```js
const students = [
    { name: 'Tom', class: "Blue" },
    { name: 'Pom', class: "Blue" },
    { name: 'Max', class: "Red" },
    { name: 'Alex', class: "Red" },
    { name: 'John', class: "Yellow" }
];

let klasses = {};

for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  let student = students[i];
  let klass = student.class;

  if (!klasses[klass]) {
    klasses[klass] = [student.name];
  } else {
    klasses[klass].push(student.name);
  }
}

console.log(klasses);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let classes = {};

for(let student of students) {
  classes[student.class] = [...classes[student.class] || [], student.name];
}

console.log(classes);
```