# Pulling object elements from an array of objects and organizing them into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

After days of hairpulling, I decided to seek help:

- I have an array of objects, one for each grocery store item. Each object has 3 properties: category (string for category of item), itemName (string for item itself), and onSale (boolean whether it's on sale or not):

  ```
  var itemData = [
  { category: 'fruit',  itemName: 'apple', onSale: false },
  { category: 'canned', itemName: 'beans', onSale: false },
  { category: 'canned', itemName: 'corn',  onSale: true  },
  { category: 'frozen', itemName: 'pizza', onSale: false },
  { category: 'fruit',  itemName: 'melon', onSale: true  },
  { category: 'canned', itemName: 'soup',  onSale: false },
  ];
  ```
- I need to convert it into an object whose properties are the object categories. Each property is an array containing values in itemName that correspond to the property:

  ```
  {
  fruit:  ['apple', 'melon($)'],
  canned: ['beans', 'corn($)', 'soup'],
  frozen: ['pizza']
  };
  ```
- When I try to do it, I end up with directionally correct values, except they're repeated:

  ```
  {
  fruit: [ 'apple', 'apple', 'melon', 'melon', 'melon' ],
  canned: [
    'beans', 'beans',
    'corn',  'corn',
    'corn',  'soup',
    'soup',  'soup'
  ],
  frozen: [ 'pizza', 'pizza' ]
  }
  ```
- I spent hours trying to find out where I went wrong, to no avail. Here's my code:

  ```
  function organizeItems (array){
  //create output obj
  var output = {}
  //iterate over the array
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

  //iterate over the object in the array
    for(var category in array[i]){
      //if value of category isn't in output add the value to output as an empty array
      if(output[array[i]["category"]] === undefined){
        output[array[i]["category"]] = [];
        //if not --> push the itemName to the category
      } else{
        output[array[i]["category"]].push(array[i]["itemName"])
      }
      } 
    }
  return output
  }
  ```

How can I avoid the repetition and end up with the correct values in the arrays?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object)

Comment: @AbuVladdy ... At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var category in array[i]){...
```

You don't have to iterate through the entries of each object as that will add unnecessary elements to the array like in your output `'melon', 'melon', 'melon'`

---

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
const itemData = [
{ category: 'fruit',  itemName: 'apple', onSale: false },
{ category: 'canned', itemName: 'beans', onSale: false },
{ category: 'canned', itemName: 'corn',  onSale: true  },
{ category: 'frozen', itemName: 'pizza', onSale: false },
{ category: 'fruit',  itemName: 'melon', onSale: true  },
{ category: 'canned', itemName: 'soup',  onSale: false },
];

const object = itemData.reduce((acc,el) => (acc[el.category] ??= [], acc[el.category].push(el.itemName + (el.onSale ? '($)' : '')), acc), {})

console.log(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group by `category` and adjust `itemName`.

```js
const
    itemData = [{ category: 'fruit',  itemName: 'apple', onSale: false }, { category: 'canned', itemName: 'beans', onSale: false }, { category: 'canned', itemName: 'corn',  onSale: true  }, { category: 'frozen', itemName: 'pizza', onSale: false }, { category: 'fruit',  itemName: 'melon', onSale: true  }, { category: 'canned', itemName: 'soup',  onSale: false }],
    result = itemData.reduce((r, { category, itemName, onSale }) => {
        itemName += onSale ? ' ($)' : '';
        (r[category] ??= []).push(itemName);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Utilize [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#counting_instances_of_values_in_an_object)

   - make use of an [*initial value*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value) (as shown with the one line above linked example code).
   - for the OP's use case the initial value too is an empty object (literal) ... `{}` ... which inside the reducer function is referred to as `result`. The latter, while iterating the array, gets build/accumulated programmatically with each new `category` and/or `itemName`.
2. [Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) (each) `itemData`'s array `item`.
3. (Create and/or) Access the `category` specific array by using the [*Logical nullish assignment ... **`??=`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)
4. [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the correct (depending on `onSale` state) form of a category item; for instance by utilizing a [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#syntax)

```js
var itemData = [
  { category: 'fruit',  itemName: 'apple', onSale: false },
  { category: 'canned', itemName: 'beans', onSale: false },
  { category: 'canned', itemName: 'corn',  onSale: true  },
  { category: 'frozen', itemName: 'pizza', onSale: false },
  { category: 'fruit',  itemName: 'melon', onSale: true  },
  { category: 'canned', itemName: 'soup',  onSale: false },
];

// // expected result ...
// {
//   fruit:  ['apple', 'melon($)'],
//   canned: ['beans', 'corn($)', 'soup'],
//   frozen: ['pizza']
// };

console.log(
  itemData.reduce((result, item) => {

    // destructure `itemData`'s array `item`.
    const { category, itemName, onSale } = item;

    // (create and/or) access the `category` specific array.
    const categoryArray = (result[category] ??= []);

    // push the correct (depending on `onSale` state) form of a category item.
    categoryArray.push(`${ itemName }${ (onSale === true) ? '($)' : '' }`);

    return result;
  }, {})
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi my friend. I couldn't upvote bc I'm new but I wanted to thank you!  I didn't understand all of the answer as I'm only a beginner, but I now know how to do it.

Comment: @AbuVladdy ... That's why I was mentioning more than just one possibility related to [*"What should I do when someone answers my question?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). It is not just the voting. [Accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235) is another thing. As much as providing feedback in general, like continue asking in case things remained unclear or just simply saying thanks. After all, I think, the majority of people who answer do not always want to just speak/talk into the dark.