# how to create a key object and value in an array using reduce()

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have an array of objects, and I need to return an object where its key is the type of pet and its value is an array with the names of the pets. but I can't create the array of the names.

```
let pets=[
    {name:'kity', edad:10,type:'cat'},
    {name:'saske', edad:10,type:'dog'},
    {name:'naruto', edad:10,type:'dog'},
    {name:'goku', edad:10,type:'cat'},
    {name:'flofy', edad:10,type:'dog'},
    {name:'flufin', edad:10,type:'cat'},
    {name:'honey', edad:10,type:'bird'},
    {name:'silvestre', edad:10,type:'cat'},
    {name:'taz', edad:10,type:'dog'},
    {name:'piolin', edad:10,type:'bird'},
    {name:'gogeta', edad:10,type:'dog'},
]

const reduced = pets.reduce((acc, {name,type}) => ({
        ...acc, [`Type${type}`]: acc[...name]
        }), {});
```

expected

```
reduce ={
            Typecat:['kity','goku','flufin','silvestre'],
            Typedog:['saske','naruto','flofy','taz','gogeta'],
            Typebird:['honey','piolin']
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the expected output?\

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
let pets=[
  {name:'kity', edad:10,type:'cat'},
  {name:'saske', edad:10,type:'dog'},
  {name:'naruto', edad:10,type:'dog'},
  {name:'goku', edad:10,type:'cat'},
  {name:'flofy', edad:10,type:''},
  {name:'flufin', edad:10,type:'cat'},
  {name:'honey', edad:10,type:'bird'},
  {name:'silvestre', edad:10,type:'cat'},
  {name:'taz', edad:10,type:'dog'},
  {name:'piolin', edad:10,type:'bird'},
  {name:'gogeta', edad:10,type:'dog'},
];

const result = pets.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if(acc[`Type${item.type}`]) {
    acc[`Type${item.type}`].push(item.name);
  } else {
    acc[`Type${item.type}`] = [item.name];
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times; we don't need more answers to the same question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey appreciate that

Comment: thanks this question has not been asked by reduce()

Comment: It's been solved by reduce many time @Victor.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

```
const result = pets.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const values = acc[item.type] ? acc[item.type].concat(item.name) : [item.name]
  
  return {
    ...acc,
    [item.type]: values
  }
}, {});
```

Comment: With the explanation, "What you can do is", which is not useful to anyone.

Comment: the code is pretty much self explanatory if you know how to use reduce. -_-