# Merging nested array by object's ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, reduce

I have an array of objects each with a nested array and a non-unique ID. I would like to concatenate the objects subarrays where the ID's match.

With the following input:

```
inputArr = [
            {id: 1,
             days: ["2022-09-05", 
                    "2022-09-06", 
                   ]
             },
            {id: 2,
             days: ["2022-10-05", 
                    "2022-10-06"]
            },
            {id: 1,
             days: ["2022-09-05", 
                    "2022-09-06", 
                    "2022-09-07", 
                    "2022-09-08"]
            },
             {id: 2,
              days: ["2022-10-05", 
                    "2022-10-08"]
             },
            ]
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
outputArr = [
            {id: 1,
             days: ["2022-09-05", 
                    "2022-09-06",
                    "2022-09-07", 
                    "2022-09-08" 
                   ]
             },
            {id: 2,
             days: ["2022-10-05", 
                    "2022-10-06",
                    "2022-10-08"]
            },
            ]
```

Ideally I would like to do this without the use of for loops and instead use a map, filter, reduce strategy. I have tried a couple of variations but am having trouble with the nesting. Thanks in advance for the help! Its greatly appreciated.

Comment: or: [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object)

Answer (score 0):

My approach using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
const inputArr = [
  { id: 1, days: ["2022-09-05", "2022-09-06"] },
  { id: 2, days: ["2022-10-05", "2022-10-06"] },
  { id: 1, days: ["2022-09-05", "2022-09-06", "2022-09-07", "2022-09-08"] },
  { id: 2, days: ["2022-10-05", "2022-10-08"] },
];
const outputArr = inputArr.reduce((accArr, currObj) => {
  let ind = accArr.findIndex((obj) => obj.id == currObj.id);
  if (ind < 0) {
    accArr.push({ ...currObj, days: [...new Set(currObj.days)].slice().sort() });
  } else {
    accArr[ind].days = [...new Set([...accArr[ind].days, ...currObj.days])].slice().sort();
  }
  return accArr;
}, []);
console.log(JSON.stringify(outputArr, null, 4));
```

**Result**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "days": [
            "2022-09-05",
            "2022-09-06",
            "2022-09-07",
            "2022-09-08"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "days": [
            "2022-10-05",
            "2022-10-06",
            "2022-10-08"
        ]
    }
]
```

*Note:* `[...new Set(array)]` to get only unique values from that array.

Comment: There's no need to parse the dates; in that format they'll sort naturally with just `.sort()`.

Comment: Nice catch, I remove that helper function of sorting ,Plus I added method slice before sorting since slice modify the array I do `slice` to just sort copy not the original!

Comment: Within this solution is there a way to count the number of times a concatenation has happened? I.e in the output array there would be a "count" field which for this example would equal 1 for each object

Comment: @Code4fun First is this question answer your question? Second I don't really know what do you mean by concatenation, you could do another question and explain more about what you need and I'm or the community gonna help you!

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution but something like this could work:

```js
let inputArr = [
  { id: 1, days: ["2022-09-05", "2022-09-06"] },
  { id: 2, days: ["2022-10-05", "2022-10-06"] },
  { id: 1, days: ["2022-09-05", "2022-09-06", "2022-09-07", "2022-09-08"] },
  { id: 2, days: ["2022-10-05", "2022-10-08"] },
];
let outputObj = {};
inputArr.forEach(
  (item) =>
    (outputObj[item.id] = outputObj[item.id]
      ? [...outputObj[item.id], ...item.days]
      : item.days)
);
let outputArr = Object.entries(outputObj).map((item) => ({
  id: parseInt(item[0]),
  days: Array.from(new Set(item[1])),
}));
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    id: 1,
    days: [ '2022-09-05', '2022-09-06', '2022-09-07', '2022-09-08' ]
  },
  { id: 2, days: [ '2022-10-05', '2022-10-06', '2022-10-08' ] }
]
```