# create arrays from array containing similar path items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array like this

```
Var arr =[
            ["ali", "classroom1"],
            ["john", "classroom1"],
            ["Doe", "classroom1"],
            ["ahmed", "classroom2"],
            ["Mo", "classroom2"],
            ["Wael", "classroom3"]
           ]
```

Now I want to create arrays or slit it to get array for classroom1 and different array for classroom2 .....

I used `splice` and `map` but it seems they're not used for this

Comment: *I used splice and map but it seems they're not used for this*. Show what you have tried so far...

Comment: You can use `forEach`, `reduce` here. All you have to do is loop over `arr` and push elements in new array.

Comment: or [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object)

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like this:

```js
let arr =[
    ["ali", "classroom1"],
    ["john", "classroom1"],
    ["Doe", "classroom1"],
    ["ahmed", "classroom2"],
    ["Mo", "classroom2"],
    ["Wael", "classroom3"]
];

let classrooms = new Map();

for (let item of arr) {
    const [name, classroom] = item;
    if (!classrooms.has(classroom)) {
        classrooms.set(classroom, []);
    }
    classrooms.get(classroom).push(name);
}

console.log(classrooms);
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer. But I don't know the name of class to check for it in filter. I get the data dynamically and the names of classrooms is not known by me

Comment: Can you solve that. I get the array dynamically

Comment: It doesn't work