# convert similar objects in an array into a single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array object like this

```
[
   {category_name: "category_1", id: [1]},
   {category_name: "category_2", id: [1]},
   {category_name: "category_1", id: [2]},
   {category_name: "category_3", id: [2]},
   {category_name: "category_2", id: [3]},
   {category_name: "category_2", id: [4]},
   {category_name: "category_3", id: [4]},
   {category_name: "category_2", id: [5]},
   {category_name: "category_3", id: [5]},
   {category_name: "category_3", id: [6]},
],
```

how can i convert it to an array like this

```
[
   {category_name: "category_1", id: [1,2]},
   {category_name: "category_2", id: [1,3,4,5]},
   {category_name: "category_3", id: [2,4,5,6]},
]
```

exactly the category names will be reduced to odd numbers and their ids will be collected in an array

Comment: Hi codeko, welcome to SO! Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

Comment: Also, try searching for "group array of objects by property aggregate into array"

Comment: There are few ways to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects
this will show you the right direction

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object is aslo helpful reference for your case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: @AustinTFrench no but i found the answer i needed