# Grouping objects js

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm just learning and I can't group the object

I need to group objects by the "product" field and filter by the "product" field in the "keyResults" and "metrics" fields

I know that this is done using the reduce function, but I can't, I also tried using the Lodash sortby function, but this is not what I need

Help please:(

```
const a = {
  products: {
    keyResults: [
      {
        leader: "Aaron",
        product: "Product 1"
      },
      {
        leader: "Addie",
        product: "Product 1"
      },
      {
        leader: "Mindy",
        product: "Product 1"
      },
      {
        leader: "Wiley",
        product: "Product 2"
      },
    ],
    metrics: [
      {
        leader: "Aaron",
        product: "Product 1"
      },
      {
        leader: "Wiley",
        product: "Product 2"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Here's what I expect

```
const b = {
  products: [
    {
      product: "Product 1",
      keyResults: [
        {
          leader: "Aaron",
          product: "Product 1"
        },
        {
          leader: "Addie",
          product: "Product 1"
        },
        {
          leader: "Mindy",
          product: "Product 1"
        }
      ],
      metrics: [
        {
          leader: "Aaron",
          product: "Product 1"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      product: "Product 2",
      keyResults: [
        {
          leader: "Wiley",
          product: "Product 2"
        },
      ],
      metrics: [
        {
          leader: "Wiley",
          product: "Product 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

This is a question about how to make a large object from an array, where there will be grouping by one of the elements of the array, but at the same time everything was elements of the array, not the object

Comment: OK. So here's what you have, here's what you expect, but what have you tried? You should add your attempts at solving this to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: or [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object) or [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-yalow-nkdtdl?file=/src/index.mjs this is my minimal solution, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect products into an object with properties as product names and use `Object.values()` to get products as an array:

```js
const products = {};

for(const key of ['keyResults', 'metrics']){
  for(const product of a.products[key]){
    const id = product.product;
    if(!products[id]){
      products[id] = {product: id, keyResults: [], metrics: []};
    }
    products[id][key].push(product);
  }
}

const b = {products: Object.values(products)};

console.log(b);
```

```html
<script>
const a = {
  products: {
    keyResults: [
      {
        leader: "Aaron",
        product: "Product 1"
      },
      {
        leader: "Addie",
        product: "Product 1"
      },
      {
        leader: "Mindy",
        product: "Product 1"
      },
      {
        leader: "Wiley",
        product: "Product 2"
      },
    ],
    metrics: [
      {
        leader: "Aaron",
        product: "Product 1"
      },
      {
        leader: "Wiley",
        product: "Product 2"
      },
      {
        leader: "Peter",
        product: "Product 3"
      }
    ]
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: wow, that's great, thank you so much, but don't tell me how you can rewrite without a construction "??="?:)

Comment: @darfil added a simpler syntax

Comment: thank you so much, this is a really exciting decision, can I ask one last question? how can I make sure that if the product does not have a property (keyResults or metrics), then an empty array is created? example "Product 3" (https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-tom-ks6vjl?file=/src/index.mjs)