# javascript data to nested struct

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I want to transform an array of arrays with headers as the first row according to a struct.
The data and structure is only known at runtime.
I could not get the objects inside the arrays to work and add the data to the right place in a recursive function.

imagine following example:

```
let data = [
    [
        'customer_id',
        'company_name',
        'order_id',
        'order_date',
        'ship_address',
        'product_id',
        'product_name',
        'quantity',
        'unit_price'
    ],
    [
        'CHOPS',
        'Chop-suey Chinese',
        10254,
        '11.07.1996',
        'Hauptstr. 31',
        24,
        'Guaraná Fantástica',
        15,
        3.5999999046325684
    ],
    [
        'HANAR',
        'Hanari Carnes',
        10250,
        '08.07.1996',
        'Rua do Paço, 67',
        41,
        "Jack's New England Clam Chowder",
        10,
        7.699999809265137
    ],
    [
        'HANAR',
        'Hanari Carnes',
        10253,
        '10.07.1996',
        'Rua do Paço, 67',
        31,
        'Gorgonzola Telino',
        20,
        10.0
    ],
    [
        'HANAR',
        'Hanari Carnes',
        10250,
        '08.07.1996',
        'Rua do Paço, 67',
        51,
        'Manjimup Dried Apples',
        35,
        42.400001525878906
    ],
    
]
```

```
let structure = {
    customer_id: 'string',
    company_name: 'string',
    orders: [
        {
            order_id: 'number',
            order_date: 'date',
            ship_address: 'string',
            order_details: [
                {
                    product_id: 'number',
                    product_name: 'string',
                    unit_price: 'number',
                    quantity: 'number'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

```
let result = [
    {
        customer_id: 'CHOPS',
        company_name: 'Chop-suey Chinese',
        order_ids: [
            {
                order_id: 10254,
                order_date: '11.07.1996',
                ship_address: 'Hauptstr. 31',
                order_details: [
                    {
                        product_id: 24,
                        product_name: 'Guaraná Fantástica',
                        quantity: 15,
                        unit_price: 3.6
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        customer_id: 'HANAR',
        company_name: 'Hanari Carnes',
        order_ids: [
            {
                order_id: 10250,
                order_date: '08.07.1996',
                ship_address: 'Rua do Paço, 67',
                product_ids: [
                    {
                        product_id: 41,
                        product_name: "Jack's New England Clam Chowder",
                        quantity: 10,
                        unit_price: 7.7
                    },
                                        {
                        product_id: 51,
                        product_name: 'Manjimup Dried Apples',
                        quantity: 35,
                        unit_price: 42.4
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                order_id: 10253,
                order_date: '10.07.1996',
                ship_address: 'Rua do Paço, 67',
                product_ids: [
                    {
                        product_id: 31,
                        product_name: 'Gorgonzola Telino',
                        quantity: 20,
                        unit_price: 10
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

as you can tell, this is data from the Northwind database.

I did try to iterate over the struct properties and rows and recursively set the properties of an object with help of an access stack. The assignment of data to array positions at a deeper nesting level did not work properly.

Transposing the data and turning each column into a set and storing the rowIndex, at which a new unique value starts did help, but I still did not find a working solution.

I expect something like this:

```
function transformData(data: (string | number)[][], structure: any): any {     
    let result = {};
    ...     
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please include your attempt and we can go from there.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object)

Comment: How are you supposed to determine which field to use as the unique key for grouping?  In your example, "orders" belong to a specific customer_id, but there is no link between customer_id and the orders array in the structure.